# SSL Handshake is failing in NGinx Upstream

Tags: ssl, nginx, self-signed

I am using a self signed certificate in the upstream. The upstream is reachable from the cURL but not from NGinX. Here is the process I followed.

I changed hosts file and add upstream IP with a domain name.

`10.0.1.2 xxx.yyy.com`

Then I used below command to access the application and it was successful.

`curl GET "https://xxx.yyy.com/test" --cacert /etc/upstream.ca-cert.crt -v`

Then I wanted to access the application through a NGinX. So I want to create secure connection between client and NGinX server and also between NGinX server and the application. The connection between client and NGinX works fine but the handshake between NGinX server and the application not works properly.

These are the configuration.

```
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        server_name xxx.yyy.com;

        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_pass https://backend-server;
                proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/upstream.ca-cert.crt;
                proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/upstream.ca-cert.key;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                rewrite ^(.*):(.*)$ $1%3A$2;
        }
```

```
upstream backend-server {
        ip_hash;
        zone backend 64k;
        server 10.0.1.2:443     max_fails=1000 fail_timeout=30s;
}
```

Below is the error log in NGinX.

```
2019/12/05 06:46:40 [error] 5275#0: *2078 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: xxx.yyy.com, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.0.1.2:443/carbon", host: "xxx.yyy.com"
```

Comment: The `proxy_ssl` statements are for client certificate authentication. You shouldn't need to tell Nginx the CA of the server for it to connect.

Comment: Aren't `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` are for client certificate authentication?

Comment: No. Those are for the server certificate between the browser and the reverse proxy. You didn't use a `--cert` option with `curl` so you are not using a client certificate to connect upstream, so `proxy_ssl_certificate` is not required.